# Intersection bewtween line and path/polygon Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

We're creating a small application on javascript using fabric.js, where we place shapes on a canvas and connect them with lines. There's different shapes, some created with fabic.js' [Polygon](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polygon.html) and some with [Path](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Path.html). The lines go from center to center, and update correctly when moving either object.

This lines also have a small arrow head at the end. But I'd like to place this shape at the point where the line intersects with the object, so it's always visible. I've tried with the fabric.js intersection functions, but can't wrap my head around how they work beyond just knowing if two objects intersect as shown at the [intersection demo](http://fabricjs.com/intersection).

So the question is: how can I find the point where a shape intersects whith a line?

This is an overwiew of how we have it working:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function addChildMoveLine(options) {
  var object = options.target;
  var objectCenter = object.getCenterPoint();

  if (object.addChild) {
    if (object.addChild.from) {
      object.addChild.from.forEach(function(line) {
        var currentLineWidth = line.getStrokeWidth();
        line.set({
          'x1': objectCenter.x - currentLineWidth / 2,
          'y1': objectCenter.y - currentLineWidth / 2
        });
      });
      // Here we want to calculate the intersection between the object and the line.
    }
    if (object.addChild.to) {
      object.addChild.to.forEach(function(line) {
        var currentLineWidth = line.getStrokeWidth();
        line.set({
          'x2': objectCenter.x - currentLineWidth / 2,
          'y2': objectCenter.y - currentLineWidth / 2
        });
      });
      // Calculate the intersection on the other end.
    }
  }

  canvas.renderAll();
}

function addItem(x, y) {
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 50,
    fill: "#faa",
    scaleY: 0.5,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });

  var text = new fabric.IText("text", {
    fontSize: 15,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });

  var group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
    // any group attributes here
    left: x,
    top: y
  });

  canvas.add(group);
  canvas.renderAll();

  return group;
}

function makeLine(coords) {
  var line = new fabric.Line(coords, {
    fill: "#000",
    stroke:"#000",
    strokeWidth: 3,
    selectable: true
  });

  fromObject.addChild = {
    // this retains the existing arrays (if there were any)
    from: (fromObject.addChild && fromObject.addChild.from) || [],
    to: (fromObject.addChild && fromObject.addChild.to)
  }
  fromObject.addChild.from.push(line);
  // to-object:
  toObject.addChild = {
    from: (toObject.addChild && toObject.addChild.from),
    to: (toObject.addChild && toObject.addChild.to) || []
  }
  toObject.addChild.to.push(line);

  return line;
}

canvas.on('object:moving', function(e){
  addChildMoveLine(e);
})

var fromObject = addItem(50, 100);
var toObject = addItem(300, 100);

var from = fromObject.getCenterPoint();
var to = toObject.getCenterPoint();
var coords = [from.x, from.y - 3 / 2, to.x, to.y - 3 / 2];
var line = makeLine(coords);
canvas.add(line);
line.sendToBack();
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tyhw7dud/) with the exxampl working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Clarified question and added code and JSfiddle.

Comment: what is your question and where is the code?

Comment: added some code and clarified the question, thanks @MauroAguilar